# Сохранение состояния radiobutton c#

Tags: c#

У меня в программе есть Combobox с четырьмя значениями и четыре radiobutton'a. Мне нужно выбрать первый элемент в combobox, нажать на нужные radiobutton'ы, выбрать второй элемент опять нажать на нужные и так со всеми элементами. А потом когда я выберу опять первый элемент в combobox мне нужно чтобы значения на радиобаттонах стояли также как я выбрал в первый раз. Возможно ли где-то хранить их состояние?

Comment: можно, к примеру в `settings.json` или в классе, или в глобальном листе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал без динамических имён, и массивов для большего понимания кода.

```
class Rbactive
{
    public bool rb1 { get; set; }
    public bool rb2 { get; set; }
    public bool rb3 { get; set; }
    public bool rb4 { get; set; }

    public int cb { get; set; }
    public Rbactive() { }
}

private List<Rbactive> list = new List<Rbactive>();
private void LoadRb()
{
    foreach(var item in comboBox1.Items)
    {
        var mem = new Rbactive();
        mem.cb = comboBox1.FindString(item.ToString());
        mem.rb1 = radioButton1.Checked;
        mem.rb2 = radioButton2.Checked;
        mem.rb3 = radioButton3.Checked;
        mem.rb4 = radioButton4.Checked;
        list.Add(mem);
    }
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Checked = list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb1;
    radioButton2.Checked = list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb2;
    radioButton3.Checked = list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb3;
    radioButton4.Checked = list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb4;
}
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb1 = radioButton1.Checked;
}
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb2 = radioButton2.Checked;
}
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb3 = radioButton3.Checked;
}
private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].rb4 = radioButton4.Checked;
}
```